# How do I create a stable Django/Python template on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, python, django

My current Django template on EC2 is using a number of easy-install packages always because there is no matching yum package.  Unfortunately, easy-install has a disconcertingly high failure rate.  Every few weeks a new easy-install package fails to install on instance launch.

Currently it is pyOpenSSL (which does not have a yum for Python 2.6)

How are other Django/Python admins handling this on EC2?  Do you have all the tarballs as attachements?  That seems to be where I am getting to ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pinpoint a working configuration and force **easy_install** to install the exact same versions of the packages each time with the following command:

```
easy_install $package==$version
```

Also, you could consider **pip**, because it provides some benefits over **easy_install** and seems to be the widely accepted solution in the Python community lately. You can install it with the following command:

```
easy_install pip
```

And then install packages with:

```
pip install $package==$version
```